# understanding socket.io callbacks

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to make certain websocket emits are received both way communication, so if a message gets lost from client, client retries, and same with server.  I am not very familiar with callbacks and all i have read is they exist and you can use them but I am not finding any good examples of how to use them, or I don't understand the examples.

This is essentially my code right now.

In index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            namespace = '/socket';

            // Connect to the Socket.IO server.
            // The connection URL has the following format:
            //     http[s]://<domain>:<port>[/<namespace>]
            var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);

            // Event handler for new connections.
            // The callback function is invoked when a connection with the
            // server is established.
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                isopen = true;
                socket.emit('join_room');
            });
        });
    });


</script>
```

in socks.py

```
@socketio.on('join_room', namespace='/socket')
def on_room():
    if 'uid' not in session:
        session['uid'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    room = str(session['uid'])

    print('join room {}'.format(room))

    join_room(room)
```

So in this example, the client html code emits join_room and I want the client to verify the server has received it, and if not try to emit join_room again.

This would have to happen in both directions.

Is there a way to have this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback on your emit call:

```js
socket.emit('join_room', () => { console.log('callback received!'); });
```

If you want the server to pass information in the callback, then add a return statement in the server handler:

```py
@socketio.on('join_room', namespace='/socket')
def on_room():
    if 'uid' not in session:
        session['uid'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    room = str(session['uid'])

    print('join room {}'.format(room))

    join_room(room)

    return 42
```

And then whatever the server returns is passed as an argument to your callback:

```js
socket.emit('join_room', (arg) => { console.log('callback received with ' + arg); });
```